# Use ntile() with group_by() with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, percentile

I want to calculate the quintile of groups in a data.frame such as this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)))
```

Using the `ntile()` function and `group_by` from `dplyr`, I thought I could get the grouped quintiles such as here. However, as we can see from the table, the quintiles have been calculate with respect to the whole dataset. I would want to get a result where there is `10` for each quintile for `A` and `B` in this case.

```
df$z <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(z = ntile(x, 5)) %>% pull(z)

table(df$y, df$z)

     1  2  3  4  5
  A 20 20 10  0  0
  B  0  0 10 20 20
```

Comment: Your mutate statement already adds a column `z` to your data.frame, so it's not necessary to assign it to a new column. Instead, you can do `df <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(z = ntile(x, 5)) %>% ungroup()`. This will not solve your problem, but I think using `dplyr::mutate` will work. Probably the version of mutate your code is using, is coming from the `plyr` package.

Comment: cannot reproduce your example. 
For me your code works as intended. Maybe try starting a fresh R session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure to start a new R-session and try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50))) %>% 
   group_by(y) %>% mutate(z = ntile(x, 5))

table(df$y, df$z)
     1  2  3  4  5
  A 10 10 10 10 10
  B 10 10 10 10 10
```

Also, a `dplyr` alternative to `table` would be `count`:

```
count(df, y, z)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! I am going to see which (if any) package was causing this to not work.

Comment: It was the `plyr` package, which probably overwrote the `group_by` function of `dplyr`.