# Calculate quantiles for each combination of two categorical variables in data frame

Tags: r

I would like to calculate quantiles for each combination of two categorical variables. E.g.

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)), y2=c(rep("C", 25), rep("D", 25),rep("E", 25), rep("F", 25)))
```

I tried solution shown in [Use ntile() with group_by() with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391946/use-ntile-with-group-by-with-dplyr) by extending to `group_by(y,y2) %>% mutate(z=ntile(x,2))` but did not get the expected result of two quantile groups per combination of `y` and `y2`.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(y) %>% mutate(z = ntile(x, 2))
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(y,y2) %>% mutate(z = ntile(x, 2))
df1 == df2 #suggests they are identical
```

Comment: Have you gone through all rows of `df1 == df2`? Are you sure they are all `TRUE` in the `z` column? You can use `identical(df1, df2)` to compare data frames

Comment: Yes I checked again. `identical(data.frame(df1),data.frame(df2))` is `TRUE`.

Comment: You need to run your code again. Just run exactly what you posted and have different dataframes

Comment: You are correct. Just ran it on a another computer and they are different. Must be a conflict with a package? Any ideas?

Comment: restart your R session